# What event fires if Excel VBA code execution is prematurely ended?

Tags: excel, events, vba

Is there an Excel Application or Workbook event that fires if code execution is ended from a run-time error?

I use `Application.Interactive = False` at the beginning of some of my procedures. If the code execution stops before `Application.Interactive = True` at the end of the procedure, then the user gets locked out of the Excel.

I don't want to use `On Error GoTo Error_Handler` or `On Error Resume Next`, because I want the error window to show (for the time being).

I want to add `Application.Interactive = True` to some event that fires when code execution is stopped, or the code module is reloaded.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What have you against an error handler?

For example:

```
Sub DoStuff
On Error GoTo Error_Handler

    ''Do stuff

Exit_Here:
    Application.Interactive = True
    Exit Sub

Error_Handler:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " " & Err.Description
    Resume Exit_Here
End Sub
```

Comment: I didn't know about the Resume statement. I think that'll do. I'll give it a try. Thanks!